# I couldn't get a Facebook access token to use the graph API on iOS

Tags: ios, fbconnect

I am a newbie for StackOverflow and iOS. I am trying get user informations like groups, books etc. and I need use the Facebook graph API for that. To use graph API you must use an access token.  I read article on the Facebook developer page about this topic and I wrote some code, but it didn't work. Can you help me? Is my code right or shall I use another way?

my .h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "FBConnect.h"

@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController <FBSessionDelegate,FBLoginDialogDelegate,FBRequestDelegate>{

Facebook *face;


}

@property(nonatomic,retain)Facebook *face;
-(IBAction)facePushed:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)logoutPushed:(id)sender;
```

my .m file:

```
-(IBAction)facePushed:(id)sender{

NSLog(@"FacePushed Began");
face=[[Facebook alloc]initWithAppId:@"313714785358239" andDelegate:self];
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
if ([defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"] 
    && [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"]) {
    face.accessToken = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
    face.expirationDate = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
}    
if (![face isSessionValid]) {
    [face authorize:nil ];
}
else {
    NSLog(@"Session is valid");
    }
    NSLog(@"FacePushed End");
}

}
- (void)fbDidLogin {
NSLog(@"aslan");

NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:[face accessToken] forKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
[defaults setObject:[face expirationDate] forKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
NSLog(@"%@", [face accessToken]);
[defaults synchronize];

}

- (void)fbDialogLogin:(NSString *)token expirationDate:(NSDate *)expirationDate {
    NSLog(@"%@",token);


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to check the following in your implementation :

1. you need to get a permissions before you authorize your app

   ```
    if (![face isSessionValid]) 
   {           
       NSArray *permissions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                           @"user_likes", 
                           @"read_stream",
                           @"publish_stream",
                           nil];
      [face authorize:permissions];

      [permissions release];
   }
   ```
2. you need to add the following functions in your application delegate(the *facebook* object here is your instance value of FaceBook Class).

   ```
   // Pre 4.2 support
   - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url 
   {
      return [facebook handleOpenURL:url]; 
   }

   // For 4.2+ support
   - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url
   sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
   {
      return [facebook handleOpenURL:url]; 
   }
   ```
3. in your info.plist add to URL types > URL Schemes > your facebok app ID with fb prefix (finally your value will be like this fb313714785358239).

Good Luck.

Comment: it didnt solve my problem..but i improved my code.thanks. mycode dont use delegetes i cant see my nslogs.

Comment: whats happened when you click facePush button ?

Comment: i put 2 more nslog my code first one is start of facepushed second one end of facepushed. and when i pushed facepushed i saw my new nslogs. nothig else. and it opened face login page and said that this app wanna use likes etc allow or not i clicked allow. just that.

Comment: I had some issues putting the login in a viewController. Much like you described. Have you tried to define these methods in the appDelegate? That solved for me. But, as I told, I didn't look much further in the problem.

Comment: ok check the steps in my edit if you follow it .. your app should work